# Links without http don't get linked

Tags: support, status-bydesign, markdown

Just came across this, don't know if its a feature or a bug. Basically if you don't type out http on a link in the markdown, it does not get converted to the link.

`[Link](google.com)` => Link

does not work, while

`[Link](http://google.com)` => [Link](http://google.com)

I feel that if I am using the inline markdown link syntax then I know that I'm creating a link. So irrespective of that fact that the link is correct (http), I want it to be formatted as a link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is correct and by design.

If you want a link, be explicit about the link *protocol*.

(hint: ftp:// works too.. as does https://)

Answer (score 2):

As [@JeffAtwood mentioned](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1795/250300), links ([URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL)s) have to contain the *protocol* aka [*scheme*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Generic_syntax) generally and are not valid without it – although most browsers accept just the hostnames without specifying the protocol.

However, I find displaying `[Link](google.com)` as `Link` instead of `[Link](google.com)` a bug. If a markdown transformation is not applied fully, it should not be applied at all – just like if you write one backtick (`) or an asterisk (*). The current behavior looks somewhat half-hearted.

Comment: You should also be able to omit the scheme and just use double slashes. For example, `[Ask Ubuntu](//askubuntu.com)`: [Ask Ubuntu](//askubuntu.com). I am not saying we should use that, but just that it is a possibility.